# Regex to match two or more comma separated integers

Tags: regex

I have a list of comma separated values:

```
123            should fail   // using my regex this pass 
123, 230       should pass
234, 560, 890  should pass
```

using this regex `^(\d+(, \d+)*)?$` if it is a single value, it still passes.

How can I only match 2 or more integers in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `*` to a `+`.  `*` means 0 or more matches, `+` means 1 or more.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `+` instead of `*` to make sure teh `(, \d+)` part exists at least 1 time.

```
^(\d+(, \d+)+)?
```

Check this:
https://regex101.com/r/yvWiZ0/1